# Filling up form using perl WWW::Mechanize::Formfiller

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I wish to download information from the website http://revigo.irb.hr/ which have an interactive menu. I'm trying the following Perl code after fetching out the form fields using

```
perl -MWWW::Mechanize::Shell -e shell
get http://revigo.irb.hr/
fillout
...
submit
script
```

The final code is as follows:

```
      use strict;
      use WWW::Mechanize;
      use WWW::Mechanize::FormFiller;
      use URI::URL;

      my @go_terms=qw/GO:0006612 GO:0045862 GO:0048545 GO:0007568 GO:0046326 GO:0051901  GO:0010524 GO:0006044 GO:0032024/;
      my $go_string=join("\n",@go_terms);
      my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );
      my $formfiller = WWW::Mechanize::FormFiller->new();
         $agent->env_proxy();

      $agent->get('http://revigo.irb.hr/');
      $agent->form_number(1) if $agent->forms and scalar @{$agent->forms};
      $formfiller->add_filler( 'goList' => Fixed => $go_string);
      $formfiller->add_filler( 'cutoff' => Fixed => '0.4' );
      $formfiller->add_filler( 'isPValue' => Fixed => 'yes' );
      $formfiller->add_filler( 'whatIsBetter' => Fixed => 'higher' );
      $formfiller->add_filler( 'goSizes' => Fixed => '0' );
      $formfiller->add_filler( 'measure' => Fixed => 'SIMREL' );
      $formfiller->fill_form($agent->current_form);

   my $request = $agent->click("startRevigo");
      print $request->as_string;
```

However I'm getting the following error message *"Error POSTing http://revigo.irb.hr/revigo.jsp: Internal Server Error at revigo.mechanize.pm line 21"*
Can anybody help me to solve the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Originally the 21st line contained my $request = $agent->click("startRevigo");
Thanks, the issue is solved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`goSizes` must have a valid value, such as `0`. You could have easily found this out yourself by using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: Thanks daxim, the codde now works with gosizes set to 0 (default value) or other suitable values that I've found in the page source